# Htmx hx-post does not contain the name of the button that submitted the form despite having name and value

Tags: forms, request, htmx

I have Django form that have 2 different submit button, i need to know which button is clicked. But the button did not include in request.POST ( I am using htmx to issue a POST request )

This is my form:

```
<form hx-post="{% url 'recomposition:akb-edit' %}" hx-target="#target-{{this_month}}-{{data.pk}}" hx-swap="outerHTML" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 ...
    <div class="form-group modal-footer p-0">
        <div class="btn-group d-flex w-100" role="group" aria-label="...">
            {% if this_month != 0 %}
            <button type="submit" value="delete" name="delete" class="btn btn-danger w-100" {%if not is_month %}disabled{% endif %}>Delete changes</button>
            {% endif %}
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary w-100" onclick="closeModal()">Close</button>
            <button type="submit" value="save" name="save" class="btn btn-primary w-100" >Save changes</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

I didnt know whats wrong the last time I encounter this if i forgot to included the name but now i have the name and value but id didnt show up in `request.POST`

Comment: Are you submitting the form using some JavaScript? Normally the functions used to do so won't send your button values. htmx probably is using some JavaScript behind the scenes, this is not a Django problem at all, please  edit and remove it.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat edit my question, yes htmx is using AJAX

Comment: try `<button hx-vals='{"foo":"bar"}' name="foo" value="bar"></button>`

Comment: See this open issue: https://github.com/bigskysoftware/htmx/issues/1132

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use the **same name** for the two submit button and then to retrieve the value of btn parameter:

```
<button type="submit" name="btn" value="delete">Delete changes</button>
<button type="submit" name="btn" value="save">Save changes</button>
```